# Java JSONArrray iterate in Javascript providing 'undefined' result

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

I want to iterate the JSONArray in my Java servlet into a JSP page using javascript. 
This is my java codes in servlet,

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
for (int t = 1; t < row; t++) {
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
                    object.put("oid", "ghf");
                    object.put("cid", "fgh");
                    object.put("oid", "hf");
                    object.put("cid", "fir");
                    array.add(object);
```

in JSP,the

```
            var obj = '<%=array%>';
            var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
            alert("myJSON = " + myJSON);
            for (var i = 0; i < myJSON.length; i++) {
                document.write('<h4>' + myJSON[i].cid + '</h4>');
            }
```

Thankyou for helping.

The output is

> undefined

Comment: did you put the array to request object? request.setAttribute("array", array);

Comment: No i put it as `session.setAttribute(""array", array");`  in my servlet. And retreived in jsp as `JSONArray array = (JSONArray) session.getAttribute("array");`

Comment: try directly accessing like this , var obj = '${sessionScope.array}';

Comment: el expression is providing the JSONArray in JSP.But when iterating array, it provides**undefined** for multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you.

Firstly, get JSON string from session scope and output:

```
[{"oid":"hf","cid":"fir"},{"oid":"hf","cid":"fir"},{"oid":"hf","cid":"fir"}]
```

and convert it to JSON object because of double quotes `[]` surrounding string and output :

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

Finally, traversing it using jquery.

```
<script>
   var obj = '${sessionScope.array}';
   var myJSON = JSON.parse(obj); // Convert JSON string to JavaScript object
   console.log("myJSON = " + myJSON);

   $.each(myJSON, function(index, element) {
     document.write('<h4>' + element.cid + '</h4>');
   });
</script>
```